# Order posts by advanced custom field (switcher)

Tags: wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a website for a realtor. There is a page where the properties are listed with image, title, excerpt and 2 custom fields for location and price. I have already inserted a filter for the size (1-2 rooms, 3-4 rooms, 5-6 rooms, houses) of the property. The customer should also be able to sort the properties by location (ascending or descending) or price (ascending or descending) like on their current website: http://urbida-immo.ch/verkauf/urbida.php?typ=1

Here's my code right now:

```
<div class="filter"> 
<input type="radio" id="reset" name="color"/>
<label for="reset">Alle</label>
<input type="radio" id="kategorie-1-2-zimmer" name="color"/>
<label for="kategorie-1-2-zimmer">1 - 2 Zimmer</label>
<input type="radio" id="kategorie-3-4-zimmer" name="color"/>
<label for="kategorie-3-4-zimmer">3 - 4 Zimmer</label>
<input type="radio" id="kategorie-5-6-zimmer" name="color"/>
<label for="kategorie-5-6-zimmer">5 - 6 Zimmer</label>
<input type="radio" id="kategorie-haeuser" name="color" />
<label for="kategorie-haeuser">Häuser</label>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( 'cf' ); ?> role="article">
        <div class="col-1of3">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php
               if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                   the_post_thumbnail('4zu3');
               }
            ?></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2of3">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <?php if (get_field( 'adresse' ) ): ?> 
                <p><?php the_field('adresse'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>                                     
            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <?php if (get_field( 'verkaufspreis' ) ): ?> 
                <p><?php the_field('verkaufspreis'); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?> 
        </div>
    </article>

<?php endwhile; ?>                          
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should post code of the filter, and we could help you figure out why it is not working, now you're just asking that someone else code the filter for you.

I personally would get all the properties via a WP_Query, label each property with data-attributes for each of the filter variables, then add a event listener with JS for each radio-button. Then use a library that handles the logic, like http://www.listjs.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My filter for the size is already working. I just need an input how to achieve a sorting for the 2 acf-fields.